# DateTime hex format decipher

Tags: date, timestamp, hex

I am working on a little puzzle. I have some timestamps that I know they are timestamps but can't figure out how they are encoded.

```
3ebf5b89 means 08-October-2013 hour 8 AM but minute I can't provide neither second 
3ebd5f09 means 09-October-2013 hour 8 AM Unknown minute/second.
3ea15d09 means 11-October-2013 hour 8 AM Unknown minute/second but before half past hour.
```

Any ideas on the encoding?

The weird part is that the dates seem to become lower values as days pass.

If I convert to decimal and substract the big date from the small date I get a value witch converted in seconds is around the days between two dates with a 5 hour error per day.

LE:

I managed to get more accurate time stamps :

```
3ea02d09 - Oct 11th, 2013 at 17:10 (hour:minute)
3ea7ff89 - Oct 12th, 2013 at 14:28
3ea7cf09 - Oct 12th, 2013 at 15:34
```

Comment: Are you sure those are timestamps?

Comment: @sara yes, either are encrypted with some kind of custom algo. unfortunatley I can't figure them out.

Comment: Can you give us any hints about where these came from?

Comment: @MattJohnson time attendance device that runs embedded linux

Comment: Really? That should be in the manual then.  Can you tell us which make/model?

Comment: Just looking at the last three, they're neither increasing nor decreasing.  Either you transposed them incorrectly, or they're not timestamps.  I assume you extracted them from some data file or packet intercept?  I think there are more bits to consider than what you show here.

Comment: @MattJohnson why it should be in the manual may I ask ? I extracted them from a sqlite and the field is sugestivly named timestamp so either the field name is wrong or is wierdly encrypted.

Comment: ahhh.. now we are getting somewhere.  You didn't mention sqlite before.  What is the sqlite data field type?  Or are you pulling it from the binary of the data file directly?

Comment: it's varchar and it's exactly how i pasted it here. I use navicat to open it so I am not extracting it raw

Comment: So a time and attendance device writes this hex string as its timestamp to a sqlite table, and there is no detail about it in the documentation?  Seems like it's failing to do its primary function.  What good is a time recording device if you can't read the data it recorded?

Comment: Are you at liberty to add an entry, or modify an entry, in the sql database by hand and see how it comes out the other end? It would be interesting to see what happens if you increment by one. If it's encrypted we should get a failure, no (as opposed to the date appearing to be n seconds or ms in the future)? Also, is the last digit is always '9' or only in these 6 examples?

Comment: @Charlesism always 9 i guess it could be the year.I will try what you suggested.

Comment: How long ago was this device created? For a hex entry in an SQL db, the year is more likely to start at the left (and we do have 3ea for all the entries). The 9 seems weird. If it were a zero, I'd assume all the time stamps started at something dot zero seconds. I can't think of a great explanation for 9 though. Maybe some type of flag? That would be somewhat crazy.

Comment: @opc0de have a look at my answer. Can you provide the exact UNIX timestamps (local to your system) for the last three entries?

Answer (score 1):

it seemed that the timestamp uses Pi as its base to calculate the time!?

3ea7ff89 - 12 October Hour 14 Minute 28
3ea7cf09 - 12 October Hour 15 Minute 34

difference: 12416 ~ 66 minutes
if we divide it by 60 for 60 seconds per minute an after that we divide it by 66 for the minutes difference we get
3.13535353535 that is realy close to Pi.
if we use pi to reverse the formular:
Pi*66*60=12440 thats in the error range of the not delivered seconds in your timestamps.

Comment: you write that 12416 is ~66 minutes.

I'd agree except that it appears that -12416 is ~66 minutes.

3ea7ff89 - 12 October Hour 14 Minute 28
3ea7cf09 - 12 October Hour 15 Minute 34

Note that the value for 12th Oct, 14:28 is higher than the value for 12th October 15:34.

Unless opc0de accidentally interchanged those two ...

Comment: That seems far fetched, is there any reason a sane programmer would ever mix pi with a date/time entry? I'm not a mathematician but I can't think of why it should ever happen.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder those HEX converted to Decimal has some relation to [Unix Epoch](http://www.epochconverter.com/) time :

Those Hex numbers are translating to some valid Dates though different from what you mentioned those are :

```
Hex 3ebf5b89 = Decimal 1052728201 = Mon, 12 May 2003 08:30:01 GMT

Hex 3ebd5f09 = Decimal 1052598025 = Sat, 10 May 2003 20:20:25 GMT

Hex 3ea15d09 = Decimal 1050762505 = Sat, 19 Apr 2003 14:28:25 GMT


Hex 3ea02d09 = Decimal 1050684681 = Fri, 18 Apr 2003 16:51:21 GMT

Hex 3ea7ff89 = Decimal 1051197321 = Thu, 24 Apr 2003 15:15:21 GMT

Hex 3ea7cf09 = Decimal 1051184905 = Thu, 24 Apr 2003 11:48:25 GMT
```

Comment: tryed that too but it doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to play around with the binary form of your inputs and using the bitwise [XOR (the poor man's cipher)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) operator between the value and the corresponding UNIX timestamp.

This is what I've got so far:

```
(1381507800 ^ 0x3ea02d09) = 0110110011111 00000001111 11 010 001

(1381584480 ^ 0x3ea7ff89) = 0110110011111 11010110001 11 101 001

(1381588440 ^ 0x3ea7cf09) = 0110110011111 11010010010 11 010 001
```

- 16bits + 2bits stay stable.
- The first 13bits plus the last 3bits (which make 16bits if combined) make me think of some kind of rotate shift left.

Please note that my timezone is UTC+1 and thus my UNIX time stamps may not be exact. It would be great if you can get the corresponding timestamps on your system to push this lead further.